# how do i select all a tags with href="#xyz"

Tags: javascript, events, css-selectors

using pure javascript can i select all a tags with href="#xyz". And also i would like to trigger some event while clicking on that element too...

how can i do that?

PS: pure javascript means without using jquery or other frameworks

Comment: Please define "pure JavaScript". Do you mean "Without using Flash or Java?" or do you mean "Without using a largish collection of prewritten JavaScript that has been conveniently bundled up into a package and called YUI, jQuery or similar"?

Comment: i mean without using jquery or other frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<=document.links.length;i++) {
  if (document.links[i].href == '#xyz') {
    // here you will have "selected only the ones with #xyz
    // Just be careful with the test, it will require a http://..../ I believe
  }
}
```